# How to define the icon of a Dock in pyqtgraph?

Tags: icons, pyqtgraph, dock

In pyqtgraph, Docks can be torn out of the DockArea by dragging or double clicking. The popups use a default icon. I would like to define my own icon. In the code below I set the application window. The same code has no effect on the dock, though there is no error message.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QVBoxLayout
from pyqtgraph.dockarea import Dock, DockArea
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon

class Foo(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)        
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('direction'))
        lay = QVBoxLayout(self)        
        da = DockArea()
        d = Dock("Dock")
        d.setWindowIcon(QIcon('direction')) # no effect
        da.addDock(d)
        lay.addWidget(da)
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Foo()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked in the source code of Dock and DockArea of pyqtgraph and found out I had to overwrite [floatDock](https://pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/pyqtgraph/dockarea/DockArea.html#DockArea.floatDock) function.

I created a function

```
def floatDockPatched(self, dock):
    """Removes *dock* from this DockArea and places it in a new window."""
    area = self.addTempArea()
    area.win.resize(dock.size())
    area.win.setWindowIcon(QIcon("res/haip.png"))
    area.win.setWindowTitle(dock.label.text())
    area.moveDock(dock, 'top', None)
```

and assigned it to the class as overwrite

```
DockArea.floatDock = floatDockPatched
```